# Bootstrap navbar on full right side of the screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

someone of you have a template or any suggestion to create a navbar like the addthis.com website?
Thank you very much
Fab

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! My suggestion: Read the Bootstrap documentation at www.getbootstrap.com. Try something by your own and share  your code with us so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no element for this in Bootstrap as of yet.  However there is bootstrap drawer by Ryan Walters which adds in this element.  You can add a button and call it to the right hand side of the screen if you wish.

http://clineamb.github.io/bootstrap-drawer/customize.html

https://github.com/ryanwalters/bootstrap-drawer